# LINQ, can't construct datetime

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I need to construct linq, but day (date time type, i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day), hours and minutes (int type) stores differently. I try to make it:

```
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        IQueryable<ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2> result = null;
        if (status == MeetingStatus.RequestedOfYou)
        {

            result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
                     where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
                     select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2()
                     {
                         Name = i.UserInviter.FirstName + " " + i.UserInviter.LastName,
                         Company = i.UserInviter.Company,
                         MeetingID = i.MeetingID,
                         Time = EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(EntityFunctions.AddHours(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day, i.AllowedTime.Hour).Value, i.AllowedTime.Minute).Value,
                         Image = i.UserInviter.ProfileImage,
                         Username = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName
                     };
        }
```

but got an exception :

> {"The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data
>   type date."}

how to do it?

ADDED class MeetingModel2

```
public class MeetingModel2
{
    public int MeetingID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field "Time" in the database you're querying is likely a [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type. You cannot perform time operations like adding minutes or hours to a Date type. If you changed that field to be a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) you'd probably be okay.

Comment: field "Time" does not exist in DB at all. It's property of class MeetingModel2

Comment: Whats the data type of 'i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day' then? I'd expect it to be an integer, but I don't see an overload of EntityFunctions.AddHours that takes two integers.